# Favicon not showing properly in the address bar IE10

Tags: url, browser, favicon

http://costruireunsito.blogspot.com/p/homepage.html

I tried absolutely everything unders the sun to make this work and it's not. The favicon display correctly in the favorite folder where I bookmarked the site, cleared the cache, reopened the browser and loaded the site again, but no luck:-(

It works in all other browser, but ie10. It shows a microscopic image of the icon. I used this site to make the icon: converterhttp://convertico.com/.

Has anybody any idea why it is still displaying incorrectly in the address bar of ie10? A real nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

@user2065813 You can try to use a version to clear the cache: 
`<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=1" type="image/x-icon" />` 
Or if still doesn't work, remove the link from the head(if you have the favicon.ico on the root of your site, it will load it automatically).